# C# Finding an element in a List

Tags: c#, list, lambda

Let's say I have the following C# code

```
var my_list = new List<string>();
// Filling the list with tons of sentences.
string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
```

Is there any difference between doing either of the following ?

```
bool c1 = my_list.Contains(sentence);
bool c2 = my_list.Any(s => s == sentence);
```

I imagine the pure algorithmic behind isn't exactly the same. But what are the actual differences on my side? Is one way faster or more efficient than the other? Will one method sometime return true and the other false? What should I consider to pick one method or the other? Or is it purely up to me and both work in any situation?

Comment: Considering there is nothing populated in my_list, both will return false in about the same amount of time. If you want to find out which is faster, you could try debugging and testing which one returns a false faster, although under the shown conditions it  is highly unlikely for you to get a valid result.

Comment: @vipersassassin did you read this line? `// Filling the list with tons of sentences.`

Comment: [you decide which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: yes. first one uses method implemented inside List. other one uses Linq... Linq is more flexible.

Comment: I suggest that you read the source code of each if you want to know how they differ.

Comment: It is likely that they will have much the same results except in one situation, if you have a list that has been ordered I *think* that `Contains` will be slightly faster as it is implemented specifically for Lists and can search smartly in that situation

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre, for `Contains` it does not matter, you have to explicitly call `List<T>.BinarySearch(string)` for you to get the benefit. [Here is the source code for `Contains`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html#521b9f7129105e15)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I did actually miss that, although I was primarily concerned with him actually doing testing on his own to determine speed, and both will give the same result  in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most upvoted answer isn't completely correct (and it's a reason big O doesn't always work). Any will be slower than Contains in this scenario (by about double).

Any will have an extra call every iteration, the delegate you specified on every item in your list, something contain does not have to do. An extra call will slow it down substantially.

The results will be the same, but the speed will be very different.

Example benchmark:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    stringList.Add(i.ToString());
}
int t = 0;
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    if (stringList.Any(x => x == "29"))
        t = i;

watch.Stop();
("Any takes: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds).Dump();
GC.Collect();
watch.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    if (stringList.Contains("29"))
        t = i;

watch.Stop();

("Contains takes: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds).Dump();
```

Results:

```
Any takes: 481
Contains takes: 235
```

Size and amount of iterations will not effect the % difference, Any will always be slower.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, the two will operate in almost the same fashion: iterate the list's items and check to see if sentence matches any list elements, giving a complexity of about `O(n)`. I would argue `List.Contains` since that is a little easier and more natural, but it's entirely preferential!

Now, if you're looking for something faster in terms of lookup complexity and speed, I'd suggest a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx). HashSets have, generally speaking, a lookup of about `O(1)` since the hashing function, theoretically, should be a constant time operation. Again, just a suggestion :)

Comment: Okay so it's almost only up to one's preferences. That's what I wanted to know, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

For `string` objects, there's no difference, since the [`==` operator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,661) simply calls [`String.Equals`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,594).

However, for other objects, there could be differences between `==` and `.Equals` - looking at the [implementation of `.Contains`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1247), it will use the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, which hooks into `Equals(T)` as long as you class implements `IEquatable<T>` (where `T` is itself). Without overloading `==`, most classes instead use *referential* comparison for `==` since that's what they inherit from `Object`.